# Why regex working in javascript but not as HTML5 pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The following JS regex is working as expected

```
/^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d+)\)?)[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$/i
```

But when I use this as a HTML 5 pattern I got this error:

```
Pattern attribute value /^(?:(?:(?(?:00|+)([1-4]dd|[1-9]d+))?)[-. \/]?)?((?:(?d{1,})?[-. \/]?){0,})(?:[-. \/]?(?:#|ext.?|extension|x)[-. \/]?(d+))?$/i is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //^(?:(?:(?(?:00|+)([1-4]dd|[1-9]d+))?)[-. \/]?)?((?:(?d{1,})?[-. \/]?){0,})(?:[-. \/]?(?:#|ext.?|extension|x)[-. \/]?(d+))?$/i/: Invalid group
```

The browser telling me this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression. Invalid group"

Any help would be really appreciated as regex is not my real strength.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same pattern? It does have an invalid group, see https://regex101.com/r/ph9Je3/1

Comment: Problem is that I used the JS pattern inside the quote in HTML input tag. browser created the error pattern. how can i convert js pattern to html5 pattern

Comment: «The pattern's regular expression, when matched against the value, must have its start anchored to the start of the string and its end anchored to the end of the string, which is slightly different from JavaScript regular expressions: in the case of pattern attribute, we are matching against the entire value, not just any subset, as if a ^(?: were implied at the start of the pattern and )$ at the end.» https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern#constraint_validation

Comment: @​oxvoxic - The two patterns in your question aren't the same. You're missing out the backslashes in the one in the HTML (for instance, the one on the `(` that is a literal `(` not the start of a capture group, and on the `+` later which is also literal instead of being a quantifier). You have them in the JavaScript version, but not the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *regex* and a *regex string* are two different things.

**Regex** example:

```
/[a-zA-Z\d]+/.test('abc123')
```

Equivalent **regex string** example:

```
new RegExp('[a-zA-Z\\d]+').test('abc123')
```

A backslash in a *string* escapes the character that follows. For many characters it is a no-op, as in a `'\d'` string, which is equivalent to `'d'`. Hence you need to specify a double backslash to get `\d` that can be used in a regex string to mean a digit.

Example use in HTML5 to validate an input:

```
<input type="text" name="uname" pattern="[a-zA-Z\d]+" minlength="4" maxlength="10" />
```

So in your case, make sure to escape the backslash in the regex string:

```
"^(?:(?:\\(?(?:00|\\+)...
```

In the pattern attribute you can't specify the modifier `i` to ignore case, e.g. you need to tweak the regex string itself to be case insensitive.

Docs on HTML pattern attribute:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Answer (score 0):

JS Regex input as copied from example:

```js
/^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d+)\)?)[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$/i
```

HTML5 Regex error output as copied from example:

```html
//^(?:(?:(?(?:00|+)([1-4]dd|[1-9]d+))?)[-. \/]?)?((?:(?d{1,})?[-. \/]?){0,})(?:[-. \/]?(?:#|ext.?|extension|x)[-. \/]?(d+))?$/i/
```

From the look of it, javascript is reading your backslashes as if they were escaping characters.

From JS example to HTML error:

- `\d\d` becomes `dd`
- Any single backslash without a recognized escape character like d, another backslash, etc. just gets deleted.

There are more examples if you look through the input and the resulting error.

If you are using JS to pass this pattern to the html DOM as a string, you need to escape the backslashes. Anytime your pattern needs a backslash, you need to put 2 of them in the string. The first backslash tells the interpreter that the second backslash is a part of the text and not an escape sequence. If the pattern is stored in a tag, like your example, and you are accessing it with JS, you would still want to escape escape your `\` by replacing them with `\\`.